# LabVIEW: What is the difference between the mechanical actions "Latch until released" and "Switch until released"?

Tags: labview

In which situations should we use "Latch until released" instead of "Switch until released"?

According to [LabVIEW 2011 Help](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/changemechactofboolswitch/):

> Latch until released—Changes the control value when you click it and
>   retains the value until the VI reads it once or you release the mouse
>   button, depending on which one occurs last. You cannot select this
>   behavior for a radio buttons control.
>
> Switch until released—Changes the control value when you click it and
>   retains the new value until you release the mouse button. At this
>   time, the control reverts to its default value, similar to the
>   operation of a door buzzer. The frequency with which the VI reads the
>   control does not affect this behavior. You cannot select this behavior
>   for a radio buttons control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation explains it clearly enough.  `Switch Until Released` changes the value until you release it.  It is possible, however, depending on the complexity of your VI that you push a button and release it before the value is read.  In this case there would be no action taken on the new value.  `Latch until released` guarantees that the off/on transition is read at least once.

As for which you would use them for, it depends on your situation.  For most buttons where a click initiates an action you would generally use `Latch until released` - these are buttons where users would expect to click the button to do something or to toggle something, etc.  Using `Switch until released` in these cases would end up with some times where the user would click the button but nothing would happen.

`Switch until released` is generally used for real-time type controls where you would click and hold the button to sustain an action and then release it to halt the action.

As a general guide, you might think of `Latch until released` as ideal for discrete operations (one click, one action) and `Switch until released` for analog actions (action continues while the button is down).

Answer (score 2):

Another big difference is that `Switch When Released` and `Switch When Pressed` events can easily be triggered using the `Val(Sgnl)` property node.

This is super useful when using event-loops-as-state-machines to transition programmaticly from one event (state) to the next.